# Recommendations on a Client Host application in .Net

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, synchronization, wcf-client

My question is concerning an application that will use a host application where the database server is, and a few clients that will be sending information to the host.

Basically the host application receives some data from the clients, makes some calculations and error checking and then (if all goes well) it stores the information in the database. The data received could be easily serialized or get character separated in a string of less than 50 characters.

I know my basic option in developing this communication application is WCF and have worked with it before but my concerns for this particular case is the fact that:

1. The host and the clients will at most times be connected to the internet through wireless USB modems which as we all know do not provide the most reliable connection ever.
2. There will be many clients all sending information to the host at the same time, each having their own identification id since that determines the type of the data received and what it represents.
3. Due to the not so reliable connections i would like to be able to know if the packet has been sent successfully, and if not to be able to keep trying until the communication is complete.
4. New data will be sent from each client every couple of minutes and if lets say we have a connection failure for 5 minutes i would like to be able to send all unsent information when the connection is restored.
5. Lastly i'm kind of trying to figure how i would be able to know where to contact the host as the usb modems do not have a static ip and this could change from time to time.

My thought is to either try to establish a communication through WCF services where the clients would send all information to the host directly or maybe consider serializing the data from the clients in XML format, then upload them on a 3rd server that will be available all of the time, and then use the host application every one minute to try and synchronize the available information with the ones one the 3rd server.

Hope i made it pretty clear with this lengthy post on what i'm trying to accomplish and would really appreciate your thoughts for a project like this.

Comment: Voted to close: this is not a discussion forum.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Can you please provide an answer to what the best way to do it is then?

Comment: Best way to do what? Have a discussion? The best way to have a discussion is somewhere else. Please see the [faq].

Comment: @JohnSaunders Best way to develop such a project. Using which technologies/frameworks? My question is: What would be the best way to develop this kind of application? Edit and rephrased it for you :)

Comment: Your question is far too broad to be answered. That's why I voted to close.

Comment: Sure no problem. If anyone got a recommendation, i'd really appreciate it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of starting a discussion. Ill try and give you an answer.

I have implemented a system your describing. Based on that experience i can tell you that you will be wanting to look at a message based system to do the communication between your clients and host(s).

A message based system allows you to transparently handle the communication going on. It allows to you resend a message in case it failed to transmit.

To keep it short there are various message based frameworks available for the .Net community. To name a few: NServiceBus, Mass Transit, Rhino Service Bus, or maybe the more lightweight Agatha RRSL.

Point is, there are quite a few. Its up to you to research em and find out which one suits your needs best.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do you think an intermediary server would be a good solution?

Comment: Why do you think you would need an intermediary server? In my experience the less 'chains' in your communication path, the better. However the fact that those USB modems external IP (if im reading it correctly that is) can change could pose a problem. Your client would just connect to the host anew, but any messages that the server hasn't send back yet, will have to send back on that new connection. So you will need some kind of unique id per client. But thats a standard paradigm in this type of problem.

Comment: I would validate first you have an external address. All wireless internet providers I know of hand out internal addresses and NAT on the way out. Especially (!) wireless phone providers (which get more and more market share in this area thanks to UMTS and now LTE coming). That would basically say "external server" because you could not be reached to start with.

Comment: Exactly that. When i say intermediary server i kind of mean like a central server which will serve as a central repository. Ie. the clients will send whatever unsent information they got to the server, then the "host" will try to download and get synchronized at specific time intervals.